# How much aid does Pakistan get from US?

Tags: united-states, pakistan, foreign-aid

How much aid does Pakistan get from US currently and how much it was getting in past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be trivially answered using an internet search. Type "US Aid to Pakistan" into Google and the top result directs you to;

[US Aid](https://explorer.usaid.gov/cd/PAK?fiscal_year=2017&measure=Obligations), where you can see US Aid to Pakistan has fallen from a peak of $2.7bn in 2010 to $837m in 2017. The figures for 2018/2019 appear to be incomplete.